# "まゆんだ"の意味はなんですか？

Tags: meaning

Context: 風の又三郎

> わあ、又三郎なんぼしらなぃたってわがなぃんじゃ。わあい、又三郎もどの通りにして**まゆんだであ**。

"まゆんだであ"という言葉はあまり聞いたことが無いので古い言葉っぽいです。

この意味は何でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちょっと調べていたら意味が分かったので自己回答します。

---

まゆんだであを今の言葉に直すと、**償わないといけない**(To have to recompense)です。これは方言らしいです。
文章を今の言葉に直すと、

> 又三郎がいくら知らないといってもだめだよ。又三郎は元の通りに償わないといけないよ。

<sup>わあいはどのしようかと思いましたが結局消しました。間違っていたらご指摘ください</sup>
となると思います。

Comment: これ http://www5a.biglobe.ne.jp/~accent/kazeno/hougen.htm によると「もどの通りにしてまゆんだであ」は「 **元の通りにして**弁償しろよな」らしいですが、ちがうんでしょうかね・・ところで、ここ http://dialect.riok.net/pageF06.html によると「まゆう」が「弁償する」という意味らしいですが、「まゆ**んだでや** 」てどういう語尾になってるんでしょうね・・過去形？

Comment: @chocolate 直しました。ありがとうございます。　前後の文章を読む限り過去形ではなさそうです。「まゆう」が償うなら、「だでや」が「～しないといけない」にあたるのかなーと思っています。